# EXCEL VBA copy cells + loop + delimit

Tags: vba, excel

I have appx 3000 lines and I would like to have a pivot ready cells as an end result.

**1)** copy and

**2)** loop

Loop consist of 6 cells. D2 and D3, F2 to D4, F3 to D5 and G2 to D6, G3 to D7.

I have problems with relative positioning of the cells where to start with the 1st loop.

**3)** delimit

How can I delimit with fixed width? I have found many so called instructions, but no sample cases.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: What do you mean by `Pivot Ready cells`? I am not sure of your exact requirements. Can you explain a little bit more? If required, show us some sample data/screenshot on what you want to achieve. Also show us what have you tried till now...

Comment: `Data>>Text to Columns` has a fixed-width option.  Record a macro and modify that for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Sub LoopRange()
'officevb.com
Dim rgArray As Variant
Dim rg As Range
Dim i As integer

'if your range not mutable use
rgArray = Array("D2:D3", "D4:F2", "D5:F3", "D6:G2", "D7:G3")

For i = LBound(rgArray) To UBound(rgArray)
    For Each rg In Sheets(1).Range(rgArray(i))
        Debug.Print rg.Address
    Next rg
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I did record the macro and tried to change the parameters but something did not work ;(

Comment: @TIM: is it possible to split a cell using fixed width or combination with delimiter also in VBA?

Comment: here is a part of the code:

`Sub Macro2()
' Macro2 Macro
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, -4).Range("A1").Select
    
End Sub`

Comment: here is the test file



https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlib2495qz539ut/VBA_sample.xls